# How to convert mongodb based query to python based pymongo script?

Tags: python, mongodb, date, pymongo

I have written a mongodb query to find the records whose begin date is under 5 years. The query works well in mongo shell.

```
db.userdetails.aggregate( [ {"$match":{"appid":"58d21f30d2a57d0ec807e012", "data.begin_date":{"$exists":"true"}}},
{ "$project": { "gender":"$data.gender", "birth_date":"$data.birth_date", 
    "membership_type":"$data.membership_type", "postal":"$data.postal", "begin_date":"$data.begin_date", 
    "begin_year":{"$year": "$data.begin_date"} } },
   { "$match": {"begin_year": {"$gt": new Date().getFullYear()-5}} } ] )
```

Now I want to write this query to execute from python. I used pymongo library for that.

```
pipeline = [{"$match":{"appid":"58d21f30d2a57d0ec807e012", "data.begin_date":{"$exists":"true"}}},
            {"$project":{"gender":"$data.gender", "birth_date":"$data.birth_date",
                         "membership_type":"$data.membership_type", "postal":"$data.postal",
                         "begin_date":"$data.begin_date", "begin_year":{"$year": "$data.begin_date"} } },
            {"$match": {"begin_year": {"$gt": datetime.now().year-5}}}]
```

From python-

```
collection_userdetails.aggregate(pipeline)
```

The code shows error

```
**pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: can't convert from BSON type string to Date**
```

I tried to execute query part by part and after analyzing **begin_year":{"$year": "$data.begin_date"} }** is causing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like at least one of the documents has $data.begin_date field as String, instead of Date.

try something like:

```
   db.userdetails.find({"data.begin_date":{$type:2}})
```

to find documents with string type for data.begin_date